# Equal and not equal in PHP query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I need to show a list of exhibits from a database. Some are events (shows lasting only one day), marked with a checkbox. I don't want to include those.

When running my Query without and selector, I get 103 results.

If I add this line

```
    AND `event`.`meta_value` = 'on'
```

I get 23 results (the events). It works well.

If I add that line instead

```
    AND `event`.`meta_value` != 'on'
```

I get 12 results. They are not events, but it is missing 68 posts.

I also tried using `<>` instead of `!=` with a similar result.

Comment: @Skaddict, have you been able to check whether my suggestion was true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They other 68 posts most likely have `NULL` as value, you should also be able to see this for yourself if you check the database. They won't show up with = or != ... If you want to see them you'll have to change your query to specifically look for the attribute being `NULL`:

```
AND `event`.`meta_value` IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks! I managed to get the missing results with that solution. I still don't know why some events are only fetched using `!= 'on'` but I combined both condition to get all the posts I needed.

Comment: Glad it helped, `NULL` is not seen as a value so you can't compare anything to it. that's why it's not coming up when doing `!=`. Not even `NULL` can be equal to `NULL` ;') found a nice metaphor for it. `NULL` is the abscense of an answer. if you ask 2 people how old they are, and they both refuse to answer you'll have `NULL` for both. that doesn't mean they are of equal age. Nor does that mean they have the same age. There is simply no way to compare the two :) so yes you must do both `!=` and `IS NULL` to get the complete set that you want.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, that makes so much sense now!